# IE printing out source code at random (seems very nondeterministic)

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, error-handling

Hey. the busted website is: [www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-alpha-3](http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-alpha-3/), and the specific error that I'm getting is the thing where IE prints out all my source code.

**As far as I can tell, the error is appearing at random in IE6, 7, and 8, but it's a commonly occuring error. I'm looking for explanations, debugging tools, fixes. Anything is appreciated, because I'm fully stuck.**

Here's how to reproduce:

- Add item(s) into cart.
- At the display cart (the url shud end with cart_display_ie.php)
- Use the shipping calculator over and over and over again until you get the error. It's happened one the first, second, 5th, and the 17th try.
- Reset cookies to restart from fresh

Here are some possibly relevant details

- 1and1 hosting, php from scratch, and mysql
- I'm using [Mark Sanborn's php code](http://code.google.com/p/ups-php/) to interface with UPS's servers.
- I'm using a local DTD for xhtml transitional 1.0
- This error also appears in the checkout cart and also seems associated with the UPS function.
- This isn't directly relevant, but IE also plagues me with "The XML page cannot be displayed."
- Occassionally, the "The XML page cannot be displayed" is displayed as a small canvas within the context of a source print like the error I'm printing.  It'll appear near the location of the error in html source, except the canvas has a really small width and height, and not display any further source code afterwards. I've fixed all these errors; they were all caused by improper syntax or w3 rationing of DTD downloads.
- The cart_display*.php is responsible for adding products, removing products, and calculating shipping.
- Sometimes it's something stupid like custom settings on my computer b/c I tweak with random settings that cause side effects. But I've tested in msft's VirtualPC, and had friends reproduce the error.

Here are some resources of similar problems. I haven't tried them because--even if they work--they mean that the website doesn't work at typical/default settings.

- http://www.techsupportforum.com/microsoft-support/internet-explorer-forum/168285-ie7-problem-printing-html-xml-source-rendering.html
- http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/ie6-printing-problem/160128.html

Like I said: any explanations, tools, guesses, or fixes are fully appreciated. I'm trying to finalize the site so I can present it as a beta within the week, and I'm fully stuck. Also, is there a workaround (like a tag) that can hide this error from the user?

Comment: Have you tested this from other computers? I've heard of others having similar problems and have used the fixes you linked to. I'd test for you, but I run Ubuntu/Firefox (ie no IE).

Comment: @Mark yeah, last part of "here are some possibly relevant details" mentions that my friends have reproduced the errors.  Thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I grabbed a network capture of the repro using Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com).

It looks like you're sending an HTML comment containing a webservice result before the HTML body.  It further looks like IE is subsequently sniffing this as an XML body instead of a HTML response.

It appears that if you move your HTML comment *inside* your HTML tag, the problem goes away.

Note that you should confirm changes in a new browser tab.  Once IE is on an XML page, simply hitting F5/Refresh isn't necessarily going to show you the HTML content properly due to caching of the MIME-type decision.

Comment: Hey EricLaw. Thanks, I didn't think of using Fiddler. I understand what you're saying, but am unable to reproduce with fiddler. Here it is:

<!-- HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2009 23:53:02 GMT
Server: Apache

The character u mentioned is < and not in the format "&lt;". Am I doing it wrong? In fiddler, I: reproduced the error. All correct runs were blue, and had one entry. The error was black, and included 4 additional files (*.dtd, *.ent). Then, in the "Inspectors" tab and "TextView" subtab, I c/p'ed exactly what I saw. Any thoughts? Thanks again dude.

Comment: Sorry-- I edited my response after I figured out what was going on.  Try moving the HTML comment (the <!--HTTP/1.1 --> bit) inside the <HTML><HEAD> tag.  This should allow IE to properly recognize this as an HTML file and not try to throw it into the XML MIME Viewer.

Comment: Got it. I realized that was a nonessential piece of code (it was the UPS xml response, being printed out in php scripting I did the preceded the <html> tag. @EricLaw, you're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to re-register two dlls. 
Open a elevated command prompt and type following commands
         **regsvr32 /i mshtml.dll
         regsvr32 /i shdocvw.dll**

For detailed fix steps, visit http://geekzsupport.com/internet-explorer-prints-html-source-code/